# Iterator end() function not working with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, math, iterator

When I run the following I miss the last data in the list and get the previous data. When I add a counter and try to subtract by 1 I crash. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
template <typename T>
Iterator<T> Iterator<T>::operator--()
{
    ptr = ptr->backward;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Iterator<T> DoublyLinkedList<T>::end() const
{
    Iterator<T> iObj;
    iObj.ptr = this->last;
    iObj.capacity = this->count;
    return iObj;
}


int main() {
    DoublyLinkedList<int> *d = new DoublyLinkedList<int>;


    for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i += 2) {
        d->insertLast(i);
    }

    //Get an Iterator which points at the end of the list
    Iterator<int> iter = d->end();
    --iter; 

    //Test that it does point to the first
    checkTest("testIteratorsDecrement #1", 20, *iter);
    //Test that our Iterator can move forward;
    --iter;
    checkTest("testIteratorsDecrement #2", 18, *iter);

    //move it some more
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        --iter;
    }
    checkTest("testIteratorsDecrement #3", 4, *iter);


    --iter;
    checkTest("testIteratorsDecrement #4", 2, *iter);


delete d;
return 0;
```

}

I try to fix it by doing the following but it crashes. count is a protected int.

```
template <typename T>
Iterator<T> DoublyLinkedList<T>::end() const
{
    Iterator<T> iObj;
    iObj.ptr = this->last + (count -1);
    iObj.capacity = this->count;
    return iObj;
}
```

Comment: this->last - 1, why are you adding count to the address of the last item?

Comment: What makes you think it's off by one ? `end`, conventionally, represents   one past the end, maybe this is what you're seeing. More the the point, we need a reproducible example to work with here (something we can compile)

Comment: I added more code in but I somehow output the wrong link in the list by 1. I was hoping that adding a counter would put me further at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `end()` would return a sentinel value which can not be dereferenced. It looks like you are returning a pointer to the last entry, that is the source of your off-by-one error.

As the implementor you can choose your sentinel value but it should not be a valid entry in the list.

As an aside: I don't see a good reason for having a capacity member in an iterator. How is it kept up-to-date?

Comment: Eventually i'm going to add an invisible link on the right side so I can access the full capacity with tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike arrays or vector, list does not store its elements one-by-one in memory.
Your first element may be at some **begin** address, but the next element can be **begin**+5, or **begin**-10 or something else.
Basically, this means you can't do arithmetic operations with pointers to elements of your list.
If you want some kind end element, I'd suggest making the last element of your list to point to `NULLPTR`